# UV Mapping not working? - New to Blender

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Im having trouble with UV mapping, I have a floating island I sculpted, I used Smart UV Project because I have no hope of figuring out what seams to select, but whatever I do, even using smart UV it never shows any mesh in the UV map section, every tutorial I watch the moment they unwrap or use smart UV you can see the mesh on the left, but mine never does.

All I wanted to do was sculpt a quick floating Island, paint a decent texture on it and export it, I didnt necessarily want to have to learn seams and unwrapping, it's quite frustrating.

Cant I just select a texture image and paint the thing?!

Im making a game and needed a quick way of making some decent floating islands

Image included so you can see whats going on.

[image: Floating Island]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Did you try *Material* and *Rendered preview*? Image textures are only visible there. If that doesn't work, [you can also share your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: Have you actually selected the mesh before trying to unwrap it? Press 'A' in edit mode and try again.

Comment: Sorted, thanks all!